# Infinite While loop in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am teaching myself c++ and am building a simple menu program. Im a complete noob to C++ so I apologize in advance for the question if it seems foolish. My code continuously calls getNum() and never exits, despite the correct menu selections. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void calc();
void pass();
string getNum(string num);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string num = "0";
    string menu = "Enter... \n 1 For calculator \n 2 for Passwords";
    cout << "Hello this is a sample menu program" << endl;


    while(num != "1" || num != "2")
    {
    getNum(num);
    cout << "You selected: " << num << endl;
    }

    if(num == "1"){
        calc();
    }
    else {
        pass();
    }
}
void calc() {
    cout << " You are running the calculator" << endl;
}
void pass() {
    cout << "You are running passwords" << endl;
}
string getNum(string num) {
    cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
    cout << "Enter... \n 1 For calculator \n 2 for Passwords" << endl;
    getline(cin, num);
    return num;
    }
```

Comment: So what would `num` have to be for the loop to stop?

Comment: The strings "1" or "2" should exit imo

Comment: Study your || and && again.

Comment: The while condition is always true.

Answer (score 4):

Change this condition

```
while(num != "1" || num != "2")
```

to

```
while(num != "1" && num != "2")
```

To write the condition correctly you should consider that the loop should not be repeated if num either equal to "1" or "2". This condition can be written as

```
num == "1" || num == "2"
```

However the loop shall be repeated if this condition is not true. So the condition for the loop will be repeated will look like

```
! ( num == "1" || num == "2" )
```

According to the mathematical logic this condition is equivalent to

```
num != "1" && num != "2"
```

It would be better to rewrite the loop like

```
string num;

//...

do 
{
    getNum(num);
    cout << "You selected: " << num << endl;
} while ( num != "1" && num != "2")
```

At least one iteration should be done in any case should not it?

Also define the function as

```
void getNum(string &num);

//...

void getNum( string &num) {
    cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
    cout << "Enter... \n 1 For calculator \n 2 for Passwords" << endl;
    getline(cin, num);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getNum(num);
```

In `getNum` you have a return statement that returns what the user entered. When you call `getNum` you don't save that return value.

```
num = getNum(num);
```

To make things clearer, I would remove the input parameter from `getNum`. You don't need to pass anything to it since it's job is to prompt for a number and return that number.

```
string getNum() {
    cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
    cout << "Enter... \n 1 For calculator \n 2 for Passwords" << endl;

    string num;
    getline(cin, num);
    return num;
}
```

Then change the call to:

```
num = getNum();
```

---

Another issue is your loop condition.

```
while(num != "1" || num != "2")
```

Think about what this will do if `num` were, say, `"1"`. You'd want the loop to stop, right? Look what happens if we evaluate and reduce the expression bit by bit:

```
while(num != "1" || num != "2")
while("1" != "1" || "1" != "2")
while(false || true)
while(true)
```

Well that's not right. It should have evaluated to `false`. The `||` should be `&&`.

```
while(num != "1" && num != "2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Line

```
while(num != "1" || num != "2")
```

be DeMorgan laws is the same as

```
while(!(num == "1" && num == "2"))
```

So you need

```
 (num == "1" && num == "2")
```

to be true

Hence the difficulty

apart from the other bits of the code that are in error

Answer (score 1):

You have written  while(num != "1" || num != "2")

so either num would be equal to "1" or "2" or none of these. In any condition one of these condition is true( i.e.  either num is not equals to 1 , this is true or num is not equals to 2 , this is true), therefore your while loop is always true and continuously run without stop

Answer (score 0):

this condition 
`while(num != "1" || num != "2")`
will always return true for all inputs. for example, "1", it is false on `num != "1"` but will still return true on the other condition `num != 2`, thus it will never exit (true || false == true)

also it should be

```
else if(num == '2') {
        pass();
    }
```

correct condition should be `while(!(num != "1" && num != "2"))` to only allow "1" and "2" inputs